# How to use a parameterised instance decleration (Data.Binary)?

Tags: haskell, serialization, types, instance

From Data.Binary:

```
instance (Binary e) => Binary (IntMap.IntMap e) where
    put = put . IntMap.toAscList
    get = liftM IntMap.fromDistinctAscList get
```

I thought this meant that any `IntMap (Binary e)` type would be serialisable, but it doesn't:

```
Data.Binary Data.IntMap> encode $ ((fromList [])::IntMap Int)

<interactive>:12:1:
    No instance for (Binary (IntMap Int))
      arising from a use of `encode'
```

How can I use the provided instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I thought this meant that any `IntMap (Binary e)` type would be serialisable, but it doesn't:

It does (apart from the nitpick that it should read that any `IntMap e` is serialisable if there is an `instance Binary e`).

```
Prelude Data.IntMap Data.Binary> encode (fromList [] :: IntMap Int)
"\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL"
```

The error message that you got almost certainly means that the `IntMap` that you are using is not the `IntMap` from the [`containers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) package that your [`binary`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary) was built with, but from another version. The `IntMap`s from different versions of `containers` are different types, and the `Binary` instance is only for the exact version `binary` was built with.

You probably have installed a newer version of `containers` since you installed `binary`.

Use the `containers` version `binary` was built with, by specifying a `-package` flag on the command line for ghci, and by using `Cabal` for compiling.

Comment: Ah! Appropriately, I had previously been warned that upgrading Containers would lead to problems! Thanks